# Nuxt.JS Create Custom UI Material Components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.JS, I want to create some custom UI Materials/Components for my application *(NOT A WHOLE LIBRARY LIKE VUETIFY)*.

This is my current approach:

**Minimal Example**

*~components/Materials/m-button.vue*

```html
<template>
    <button>
        <!-- ???? -->
    </button>
</template>
```

And later I want to use this Material like this:

```html
<m-button>
    Button Test
</m-button>
```

Currently, this isn't working.
I have also tried replacing the `<!-- ???? -->` with `<Nuxt />` & `<nuxt-child />` but, as expected, the page gets placed in there (*index.vue* e.g.), instead of the text `Button Test` in this example.

Can I somehow get the DOM-"children"?
Do I need to create a plugin? If yes, how?
Couldn't find anything so far, not even with Vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<slot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) for this:

```html
<template>
  <button>
    <slot/>
  </button>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-slots-wle32)